# QGIS hide the field in the feature properties form if the field's value is empty

Tags: qgis

When clicking on a feature with the [image] tool and obtaining its properties, in the form that is shown, I would like to view only the fields that are filled (not empty). In some layers I have 50 fields but only 4 are filled.

Is it possible to do it using Edit Widgets?

Comment: I believe this can only be done by creating a custom form .ui and some python.

Comment: since this question is 6 years old.. is there a solution for this?